# URL encoding not work as expected

Tags: url, encode

The file on server:
    /upload_files/=%e4%bd%a0.rar
Here =%e4%bd%a0.rar is the file name.

The javascript generate the link:

```
var h = '<a style="padding-left:10px" href="' + escape(value.file_url) + '">click_to_download</a>;
```

Here value is from an ajax request, and value.file_url == '=%e4%bd%a0.rar'

When I open the page, and click the download link, the file can't be found, the url in the address bar is

> http://www.example.com:5178/upload_files/%3D%25e4%25bd%25a0.rar

And the error message show a line:

> Requested URL http://www.example.com:5178/upload_files/=%e4%bd%a0.rar

With a common file name like  a.rar, it can be downloaded.

How to make =%e4%bd%a0.rar downloadable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution in the error page:

•Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering@allowDoubleEscaping setting in the applicationhost.config or web.confg file.